# Django Model with a Field Containing Lists / Dictionaries

Tags: django, list, templates, model

I have a Django model where one of the fields is called Title. This field is populated with a list which can contain one or more titles. Currently when I render this field in a template I get the following:

```
Title = ['Title 1','Title 2',...]
```

Is there a way to parse Python objects such as lists / dictionaries from a field in a Django model? Alternatively do I need to create a separate "Title" model and link it to the original one? Currently, the field is displayed as a string, including the list brackets.

Comment: You haven't given nearly enough information here. What is the type of the field? How are you storing the list/dict?

Comment: Which database are you using? Postgresql has an array field

Comment: I'm currently developing so I was using the default Sqlite3 database. I planned on migrating to Postgresql later. Its currently set as a Text field, since the number of titles can vary greatly in length.

Comment: With regards to the data in the field; it is loaded through a JSON file. Just looking into Postgresql, it seems that the JSON field / Array field would be the way to go.